# How to make a conductor positively charged?

Tags: batteries, charge

I want to get a conductor positively charged for a long time. However, the charge shouldn't be so small so charging by friction is not a solution for me. I've heard if you connect the + end of a battery to the object the object gets positively charged whereas if you connect the - end of a battery to the object the object gets negatively charged. Is that true?

Comment: Unless you're planning to magnetically suspend it in a vacuum forever this isn't happening.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I see what you are saying but when I said "permenantly" I was trying to say for a long time.

Comment: What is the object? What material is it made of? How is it to be supported? How much charge do you need it to hold?

Comment: Isn't this what a Van der Graaff generator is for?

Answer (score 2):

Hang your conductor from a silk thread.  (probably nylon type fishing line is fine.)  Get a butane grill lighter that has a piezo ignitor.  You squeeze and release it and get a pulse of charge. Remove the ignitor.  Put one side of the piezo to local earth and spark away.

Answer (score 0):

To store a large charge (at a given voltage) you need a large capacitor. A simple wire won't do that.

Charging by friction is commonly used to get a (very) high voltage at a very very low current, for charging a small capacitor.

Maybe you should tell us what you want to achieve?